# File System and security (PHP)

Tags: php, security

Consider a simple file upload system written in php. User has access only in admin panel. 
(Not FTP). He may change folder option from 707 to 755 for security issue.
How can do this? Can we do this from upload script ? If yes is this a secure application?

Comment: What user do you refer to? A site owner or site user?

Comment: The last number in a chmod is global access, having a 7 or a 5 gives everyone on the machine access to your files.  You need chmod 700 and should not let your friend give you security advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) for that. Every file system operation has a running risk, so consider the fact that the user might try to change the permissions of another file so you *have* to sanitize the input.

```
bool chmod  (  string $filename  ,  int $mode  )
```

> Attempts to change the mode of the
>   specified file to that given in mode.

Answer (score 2):

we can't do while uploading a script,this is not a secure way any one can hack it.
I can be done only in file uploading page code by giving chmod  through ftp.

Answer (score 2):

**This scripts removes all the dirty stuff and also checks the white file list from the directory.If the file is exists in the dir then result will be true otherwise a hacking attempt**

```
function WhitePage($page) {

        $info2 = apache_lookup_uri('src/index.php?p=' . $page);

        list($arg, $val) = explode("=", $info2->args);

        $myrequest = basename(htmlspecialchars_decode($val));

        return $myrequest;
    }

    function Read_Dir($dir, $array = array()) {
        $dh = opendir($dir);
        $files = array();
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $flag = false;
            if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && !in_array($file, $array)) {
                $files[] = trim($file);
            }
        }
        return $files;
    }

    function WhiteList($page = null) {
        $info2 = apache_lookup_uri('src/index.php?p=' . $page);
        list($arg, $val) = explode("=", $info2->args);
        // basename from the std class
        $myrequest = basename(htmlspecialchars_decode($val));

        $myrequest = trim($myrequest . '.php');
        //pathinfo from the std class
        $path = pathinfo($info2->filename);
        // get the files array
        $whitefiles = Read_Dir($path['dirname']);

        if (in_array($myrequest, $whitefiles, true)) {

            $res = 1;
        } else {

            $res = 0;
        }
        return $res;
    }

    // this is solution of this kind of the problems
    //$p='index.php?p=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00index.html';
    $p = '../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00index.html';
    $p = WhitePage($p);
    $result = WhiteList($p);

    if ($result) {
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'Die ,You evil hacker';
    }
```

Comment: This scripts removes all the dirty stuff and also checks the white file list from the directory.If the file is exists in the dir then result will be true otherwise a hacking attempt

Comment: hi lehal2, You should edit your answer rather than adding a comment, that way it's more obvious to people who see your answer next.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not understand the way web-server works. It has only one `system user` ans there is no need to change any permissions for the `site users`.

To implement an ACL feature, one need a database to hold users and rights, and some manual download method implementation, a simple one (proper headers+readfile()) or one of more complicated solutions, like nginx's x_accel_redirect

Comment: User may upload image an add to article. What about folder chmod this case? The folder may always be in 707? And what about security?

Comment: @Fel Permissions must be set just to make the site work. And depends on the server setup, not imaginable "security issues"